# Failing to convert List<Map<String,dynamic>> into List of Object in Flutter in with fromMap Constructor in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created two class named Movie and Person, where person class contains a list of Movie..

I am using toMap method and fromMap Constructor for converting into map to object and visa versa...

But in a Person class i cant understand why following statement not working

```
favmovies:map['favmovies'].map((e)=>Movie.fromMap(e)).toList();
```

i can solve with some other codes but just want to know where i am wrong in this line.

or suggest me better code

```
class Movie {
  String? name;
  String? rating;

  Movie({required this.name, required this.rating});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': this.name,
      'rating': this.rating,
    };
  }

  factory Movie.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Movie(
      name: map['name'],
      rating: map['age'],
    );
  }
}

class Person {
  String? name;
  String age;
  List<Movie> favmovies;

  Person({required this.age, required this.name, required this.favmovies});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': this.name,
      'age': this.age,
      'favmovies': favmovies.map((e) => e.toMap()).toList(),
    };
  }

  factory Person.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    List<Movie> templist = [];
    for (var x in map['favmovies']) {
      templist.add(Movie.fromMap(x));
    }
    return Person(
        name: map['name'],
        age: map['age'],
      //favmovies:map['favmovies'].map((e)=>Movie.fromMap(e)).toList();

    
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to

```
favmovies:map['favmovies'].map<Movie>((e)=>Movie.fromMap(e)).toList();
```